# When making NuGet packages from C# using GitVersion.MsBuild and dotnet pack, what determines whether the NuGet name gets a timestamp suffix or not?

Tags: c#, nuget, gitversion

I am generating NuGet packages from a C# project. My C# project references **GitVersion.MsBuild** version 5.12.0. When I build and then call **dotnet pack**, by default my NuGet gets a name like this:

**MyProject-6.0.3-mybranchname.20230324152546.nupkg**

The last part (20230324152546) is a timestamp. This gets appended when I build feature branches or master, but apparently it does not get appended when I build a *Git tag*. At least not on my CI server (which is GitHub actions in this case).

I cannot figure out what logic determines whether this timestamp gets appended or not. I don't even know whether it is controlled by GitVersion or by the **dotnet pack** command.

Can I force it to append or drop the timestamp suffix, either with a command line parameter or using **GitVersion.yml** or something in my CSPROJ or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far is to *disable GitVersion entirely*:

- Pass the parameter `-p:DisableGitVersionTask=true` to both `dotnet build` and `dotnet pack`.
- Pass the parameter `--version-suffix 'mySuffix'` to `dotnet pack`.
- Make sure that `<VersionPrefix>` is set correctly in the `csproj` file.

I think this solution is extremely ugly, but it is the only solution I have found.